# Is は a particle in こんにちは and こんばんは?

Tags: meaning, words, phrases

Is は a particle in こんにちは and こんばんは?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  This は is the same as the topic marker は.

These expressions were originally the start of a greeting, as in, [今日]{こんにち}はお[元気]{げんき}でしょうか ("You're feeling well today?") or [今晩]{こんばん}はいかがですか ("How are you this evening?"), etc.  Over time, through regular and frequent use, the opening portions came to be used independently as simplified greetings.

According to Shogakukan's [国語]{こくご}[大]{だい}[辞典]{じてん} entry for [今日]{こんにち}は:

> （「今日は…」と続けた挨拶語の下略されたもの）
>   　(omitting the portion of the greeting continuing on after "*konnichi wa*...")

Comment: I think it might be worth drawing a distinction between “is a particle” and “was originally a particle”, because IMO these words are fully lexicalized and は is not serving the function a particle normally would...

Comment: Perhaps I'm being too picky, but If that's the case, then the answer of the question should be "No, despite it used to be originally."

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, though lexicalized to the point that these phrases can be used independently, the latter at least can also be used in fuller contexts as originally composed.  Google searches for 今晩は + some other following term show no dearth of such usage, such as [今晩は寒くて](https://www.google.com/search?q="今晩は寒くて"). Daijirin also parses this as a particle: [〔「は」は助詞。「今日は御機嫌いかがですか」などの下を略した形〕](https://kotobank.jp/word/今日は-506350)  And if は is not a particle, what is it? I'd counter-claim that it's still the particle は, just that it functions differently in this specific lexicalized context.  :)

Comment: “And if は is not a particle, what is it?” < I would say it’s a kana... just like the う in ありがとう.

Comment: When analyzing things synchronically, what is most relevant is the mental model of the native speakers using it. If you want to create a complex model to say that there are multiple uses of the particle は, including a sentence-ending one that doesn’t invoke a feeling of something being missing/inferred, go ahead, but somehow that doesn’t feel right compared to こんにちは just being an expression that is made up of those sounds and no further...

Comment: @DariusJahandarie: _"what is most relevant is the mental model of the native speakers using it"_ -- if monolingual JA dictionaries state that the は is the 助詞 "は", would that not be an indication of the mental model of the native speakers using it?  Serious question, no combativeness intended.