# how to know when to say "ha" or "wa" with は

Tags: particles, pronunciation, particle-は

it is going to be the end of week 3 in learning japanese and i've noticed how sometimes in sentences the hiragana は can sound like "wa" as well, why is this so? And also when do i know when to say "wa" instead of "ha"?

from alexa the learner ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only pronounced as 'wa' when used as a particle.
Such places include:

noun+は

のは

では

ではない

ではありません

other things + は + ない

Also, curiously, in こんにちは. Not sure whether it was originally a particle there or not.

My list is probably not exhaustive but hopefully you get the idea.
I wouldn't worry about it too much. With a little time it will become obvious to you which pronunciation to use.

Please comment if you have additional uses which remain confusing.

Comment: thank you for answering my question! ありがとうございました!

Comment: Etymologically it was a particle in こんにちは and こんばんは, yes.  Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/71794/is-%E3%81%AF-a-particle-in-%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AF-and-%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%B0%E3%82%93%E3%81%AF#comment119416_71795

Answer (score 0):

One uses は and pronounces it as 'wa' when one brings up a new topic or in general when using it as a particle.

In other cases, e.g. when は is in a word, it is pronounced as 'ha'.

I hope I helped you :)

Comment: thank you! every comment counts for me so this does help a lot!